# »Das war’s« in einem Nebensatz

Tags: grammar, word-order, subordinate-clause

Was ist richtig? Keine der Möglichkeiten hört sich für mich gut an …

> **Das war’s!**
>
> *Ich weiß, dass …*
>
> … das es war.
>
> … es das war.
>
> … das war’s.

Verhält es sich ähnlich wie bei *es gibt*? Was sagen die Muttersprachler dazu?

Oder verwendet man diesen Satz etwa nicht in dieser Form?

Comment: Hier gibt's die Regel dazu: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/8857/23 (auf Englisch).

Comment: Umgangssprachlich: "Ich weiß, das war's".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 2 ist vollkommen normal und richtig:

> Ich weiß, dass es das war.

(vgl. Google-Suche [„dass es das war“](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22dass%20es%20das%20war%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=EWAfV-jCLsGTaaKtq-AP) mit ca. 346,000 Resultaten)

Option 1 ist ebenfalls vollkommen richtig, hört sich für mich als Muttersprachler wegen dem zweifachen *das(s)* nur etwas gestelzt an – schriftlich ja, mündlich würde ich eher zu Option 2 tendieren. Option 1 würde ich nur dann verwenden, wenn man *das* besonders betonen will.

> Ich weiß, dass das es war.

Google-Suche [„dass das es war“](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22dass%20das%20es%20war%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Y2AfV6bNIIb6avzmvWA) liefert ähnliche Häufigkeit, ca. 337,000 Resultate.

Option 3 hingegen ist falsch – das *es* (*’s*) steht hier an der grammatikalisch falschen Stelle.

Answer (score 5):

In Bezug auf deine auf »Das war’s!« abzielende Frage, die ich im Sinne von »Das ist erledigt/beendet/abgeschlossen!« verstehe, ist das einzig Richtige:

> (*x*) Ich weiß, dass es das war.

Richtig ist auch, wie du vermutest:

> Ich weiß, dass es das gibt.

Satz (*x*) könnte eine Antwort sein auf:

> Wir müssen klären lassen, ob sein Aus-der-Kurve-Fliegen Sabotage war.

Ein Szenario, das den Satz (*y*) »Ich weiß, dass das es war.« zu einem gültigen Gebilde macht, ist meiner Einschätzung nach schwer zu finden. (Jetzt nicht weiterlesen, sondern nachdenken!) Nach einiger Zeit ist mir Folgendes eingefallen:

> »Und ich frage Sie: Was wurde an die Wand gesprüht, **se** oder **es**«?
>
> »Ich weiß, dass das **es** war.«

Dann aber auch:

> »Wer hat die Vase zerbrochen, Katrin oder das Monster?«
>
> »Ich weiß, dass das **es** war.«

**UPDATE**

Inzwischen meine ich nicht mehr, dass der auf den ersten Blick befremdlich wirkende Satz (*y*) im Sinne der Frage falsch ist. Wird *es* z. B. durch *das Ende* ersetzt, entsteht nämlich eine korrekte Konstruktion:

> (*y'*) Ich weiß, dass das das Ende war.